# awk: mysterious double line print

Tags: bash, awk

I have a $FILE

```
1 textline1
1 textline2
1 textline3
1 textline4
```

I want to search for textline3 and make sum: 1stcolumn+1

Linenumber is:

```
lnr=$(grep -n textline3 $FILE | cut -d : -f1)
```

But when i use awk:

```
awk -v l="$lnr" 'FNR==l{ sub($1,$1 + 1); print }1' $FILE
```

I get the erroneous (3rd line is double printed)

```
1 textline1
1 textline2
2 textline3
2 textline3
1 textline4
```

Comment: Remove the `print`?

Answer (score 7):

Reason for double printing is , you are printing inside {} and using 1 as well. 1 means true and awk's default behaviour is to print.

```
awk -v l="$lnr" 'FNR==l{ sub($1,$1 + 1)}1' $FILE
```

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the usage of `grep` and let `awk` do the magic.

```
awk '/textline3/{sub($1,$1 + 1)}1' file
1 textline1
1 textline2
2 textline3
1 textline4
```

In general, you can do a `awk '/<pattern>/ { <action> }' file` for manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to increment the first field on the N<sup>th</sup> line, just say so:

```
$ awk -v line=3 'FNR==line {$1+=1}1' file  # line is more readable than l
1 textline1
1 textline2
2 textline3
1 textline4
```

Note the `1` here is triggering `awk`'s default action, consisting in printing the current line. For every line it will print the initial value but for the line number `line` it will print the 1<sup>st</sup> value with its value +1.

And that's why you see that line twice in your code: because in the action triggered by `FNR==line` you are already calling `print`.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a few problems with your script:

1. The specific bug you are asking about: You're calling `print` inside the action block and then the `1` at the end of the script is a constant true condition which will cause awk to execute it's default action of printing the record again.
2. Never use the letter `l` (el) as a variable name, it looks far too much like the number `1` (one) and so makes your code harder to read.
3. You don't need a function call to change `$1`, just do `$1++` (assuming `textline3` doesn't contain chains of white space that must not be concatenated into one blank char).
4. You don't need to use grep+wc to find lines, just keep it in awk.
5. In general you should avoid using input data (e.g. `$1`) as either the search regexp or replacement string fields of any *sub() command as that will fail cryptically given various regexp or backreference metacharacters in the input.

So your script should be just:

```
$ awk '/textline3/{$1++}1' file
1 textline1
1 textline2
2 textline3
1 textline4
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `perl`

```
$ perl -pe 's/^(\d+)(?=\s*textline3)/$1+1/e' $FILE
1 textline1
1 textline2
2 textline3
1 textline4
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/^(\d+)/$1+1/e if /textline3/' $FILE
```